# How to create folder in hadoop in year/date/time

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i have problem, how create folder in hadoop but name path folder in year,date,time.?

example:

```
i want path folder:
/user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000

i try my code:
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000
```

but i have error,

No such file or directory.

How i get path folder using hadoop fs -mkdir like /user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000.?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000?

Comment: @flowit same error i am used hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000

Comment: Then check your permissions and your hdfs mount point.

Comment: @flowit ok success. iam missed in permissions. but i have problem how i run fs -mkdir /user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000 in PIG this error No such file or directory.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run :

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hdfs/2015/10/10/0000
```

The `-p` option will create all the directories in the path as needed.  See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#mkdir for more information.